# How do I profile MySQL?

Tags: mysql, performance

What tools exist to profile MySQL, like how MSSQL 2000+ does with the SQL Profiler?

I'd want to trace things like SQL statements executed, execution times, execution plan, etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Look into enabling the [Query Log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/query-log.html) and the [Slow Query Log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/slow-query-log.html).

Answer (score 5):

if you have query logging turned on on your production/test environment [ which is not necessary the case ] you can use [mk-query-digest](http://www.maatkit.org/doc/mk-query-digest.html) from [maatkit](http://www.maatkit.org/) toolkit. it'll help you to determine which queries are most frequent/longest taking etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can also check out [MySQLTuner](https://raw.github.com/rackerhacker/MySQLTuner-perl/master/mysqltuner.pl)

Answer (score 3):

Another commercial option is [MySQL Query Analyzer](http://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/query.html) which is part of the MySQL Enterprise Monitor.  I've found it to be moderately useful in helping to profile oddball queries to figure out ways to improve their performance.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an [good article](http://wayback.archive.org/web/20120530095431/http://osiux.com/using-the-new-mysql-query-profiler) about the profiler of MySQL. Although take a look at the [explain](http://wayback.archive.org/web/20120302020704/http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/explain.html) statement.

Comment: updated to an alternative

Answer (score 1):

I've used several scripts and other tools which are all great, but i found [Jet Profiler](http://www.jetprofiler.com/) really good at giving real time monitoring and visualization of what's going on and how things are changing. The full version costs money but the restricted free version is also useful and gives you a good feel for what the full one can do.

Answer (score 0):

I use this little script. It's always been useful to me, although not anything official.

http://genomewiki.ucsc.edu/index.php/Tuning-primer.sh

Answer (score 0):

See: https://sites.google.com/site/basicsqlmanagment/ Works for me, is not a proxy profiler

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Generally we like answers on the site to be able to stand on their own - Links are great, but if that link ever breaks the answer should have enough information to still be helpful. Please consider editing your answer to include more detail. See the [FAQ](http://www.serverfault.com/faq) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend the following

- [**pt-query-digest**](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-query-digest.html)
- [**mk-query-digest**](http://www.maatkit.org/doc/mk-query-digest.html) (outdated but still works)

From the old MAATKIT Documentation

```
 Column        Meaning
 ============  ==========================================================
 Rank          The query's rank within the entire set of queries analyzed
 Query ID      The query's fingerprint
 Response time The total response time, and percentage of overall total
 Calls         The number of times this query was executed
 R/Call        The mean response time per execution
 Apdx          The Apdex score; see --apdex-threshold for details
 V/M           The Variance-to-mean ratio of response time
 EXPLAIN       If --explain was specified, a sparkline; see --explain
 Item          The distilled query
```

In the DBA StackExchange I answered [**MySQL general query log performance effects**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/8382/877). In my old post, I suggested using mk-query-digest instead of the general log or slow log. From that post, here is sample output of the query profiling done by mk-query-digest:

```
# Rank Query ID           Response time    Calls   R/Call     Item
# ==== ================== ================ ======= ========== ====
#    1 0x812D15015AD29D33   336.3867 68.5%     910   0.369656 SELECT mt_entry mt_placement mt_category
#    2 0x99E13015BFF1E75E    25.3594  5.2%     210   0.120759 SELECT mt_entry mt_objecttag
#    3 0x5E994008E9543B29    16.1608  3.3%      46   0.351321 SELECT schedule_occurrence schedule_eventschedule schedule_event schedule_eventtype schedule_event schedule_eventtype schedule_occurrence.start
#    4 0x84DD09F0FC444677    13.3070  2.7%      23   0.578567 SELECT mt_entry
#    5 0x377E0D0898266FDD    12.0870  2.5%     116   0.104199 SELECT polls_pollquestion mt_category
#    6 0x440EBDBCEDB88725    11.5159  2.3%      21   0.548376 SELECT mt_entry
#    7 0x1DC2DFD6B658021F    10.3653  2.1%      54   0.191949 SELECT mt_entry mt_placement mt_category
#    8 0x6C6318E56E149036     8.8294  1.8%      44   0.200667 SELECT schedule_occurrence schedule_eventschedule schedule_event schedule_eventtype schedule_event schedule_eventtype schedule_occurrence.start
#    9 0x392F6DA628C7FEBD     8.5243  1.7%       9   0.947143 SELECT mt_entry mt_objecttag
#   10 0x7DD2B294CFF96961     7.3753  1.5%      70   0.105362 SELECT polls_pollresponse
#   11 0x9B9092194D3910E6     5.8124  1.2%      57   0.101973 SELECT content_specialitem content_basecontentitem advertising_product organizations_neworg content_basecontentitem_item_attributes
#   12 0xA909BF76E7051792     5.6005  1.1%      55   0.101828 SELECT mt_entry mt_objecttag mt_tag
#   13 0xEBE07AC48DB8923E     5.5195  1.1%      54   0.102213 SELECT rssfeeds_contentfeeditem
#   14 0x3E52CF0261A7C3FF     4.4676  0.9%      44   0.101536 SELECT schedule_occurrence schedule_occurrence.start
#   15 0x9D0BCD3F6731195B     4.2804  0.9%      41   0.104401 SELECT mt_entry mt_placement mt_category
#   16 0x7961BD4C76277EB7     4.0143  0.8%      18   0.223014 INSERT UNION UPDATE UNION mt_session
#   17 0xD2F486BA41E7A623     3.1448  0.6%      21   0.149754 SELECT mt_entry mt_placement mt_category mt_objecttag mt_tag
#   18 0x3B9686D98BB8E054     2.9577  0.6%      11   0.268885 SELECT mt_entry mt_objecttag mt_tag
#   19 0xBB2443BF48638319     2.7239  0.6%       9   0.302660 SELECT rssfeeds_contentfeeditem
#   20 0x3D533D57D8B466CC     2.4209  0.5%      15   0.161391 SELECT mt_entry mt_placement mt_category
```

Above this output are histograms of these 20 top worst-performing queries

Example of the first entry's histogram

```
# Query 1: 0.77 QPS, 0.28x concurrency, ID 0x812D15015AD29D33 at byte 0 __
# This item is included in the report because it matches --limit.
#              pct   total     min     max     avg     95%  stddev  median
# Count         36     910
# Exec time     58    336s   101ms      2s   370ms   992ms   230ms   393ms
# Lock time      0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
# Users                  1      mt
# Hosts                905 10.64.95.74:54707 (2), 10.64.95.74:56133 (2), 10.64.95.80:33862 (2)... 901 more
# Databases              1     mt1
# Time range 1321642802 to 1321643988
# bytes          1   1.11M   1.22k   1.41k   1.25k   1.26k   25.66   1.20k
# id            36   9.87G  11.10M  11.11M  11.11M  10.76M    0.12  10.76M
# Query_time distribution
#   1us
#  10us
# 100us
#   1ms
#  10ms
# 100ms  ################################################################
#    1s  ###
#  10s+
# Tables
#    SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM `mt1` LIKE 'mt_entry'\G
#    SHOW CREATE TABLE `mt1`.`mt_entry`\G
#    SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM `mt1` LIKE 'mt_placement'\G
#    SHOW CREATE TABLE `mt1`.`mt_placement`\G
#    SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM `mt1` LIKE 'mt_category'\G
#    SHOW CREATE TABLE `mt1`.`mt_category`\G
# EXPLAIN
SELECT `mt_entry`.`entry_id`, `mt_entry`.`entry_allow_comments`, `mt_entry`.`entry_allow_pings`, `mt_entry`.`entry_atom_id`, `mt_entry`.`entry_author_id`, `mt_entry`.`entry_authored_on`, `mt_entry`.`entry_basename`, `mt_entry`.`entry_blog_id`, `mt_entry`.`entry_category_id`, `mt_entry`.`entry_class`, `mt_entry`.`entry_comment_count`, `mt_entry`.`entry_convert_breaks`, `mt_entry`.`entry_created_by`, `mt_entry`.`entry_created_on`, `mt_entry`.`entry_excerpt`, `mt_entry`.`entry_keywords`, `mt_entry`.`entry_modified_by`, `mt_entry`.`entry_modified_on`, `mt_entry`.`entry_ping_count`, `mt_entry`.`entry_pinged_urls`, `mt_entry`.`entry_status`, `mt_entry`.`entry_tangent_cache`, `mt_entry`.`entry_template_id`, `mt_entry`.`entry_text`, `mt_entry`.`entry_text_more`, `mt_entry`.`entry_title`, `mt_entry`.`entry_to_ping_urls`, `mt_entry`.`entry_week_number` FROM `mt_entry` INNER JOIN `mt_placement` ON (`mt_entry`.`entry_id` = `mt_placement`.`placement_entry_id`) INNER JOIN `mt_category` ON (`mt_placement`.`placement_category_id` = `mt_category`.`category_id`) WHERE (`mt_entry`.`entry_status` = 2  AND `mt_category`.`category_basename` IN ('business_review' /*... omitted 3 items ...*/ ) AND NOT (`mt_entry`.`entry_id` IN (53441))) ORDER BY `mt_entry`.`entry_authored_on` DESC LIMIT 4\G
```